# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-5

In   _form.html.erb

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <%= form_for(user, :html=>{:class=>'user_form_validation'}) do |f| %>
       <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :first_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :first_name%>
          <p id="first_name_error"></p>
       </div>

       <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :last_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :last_name%>
          <p id="last_name_error"></p>
       </div>
       <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Create",:id => "submit_button" %>
       </div>
    <% end%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.user_form_validation').validate({
            alert($('#user_first_name'.val());
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $(element).closest('div').append(error);
    },
    onfocusin: function(element) {          
      this.lastActive = element;
      if ( this.settings.focusCleanup && !this.blockFocusCleanup ) {          
        this.addWrapper(this.errorsFor(element)).hide();
      }
    },
    onfocusout: function(element) {         
      if ( !this.checkable(element) ) {
        this.element(element);
      }
    },
    onkeyup: function(element) {         
      this.element(element);
      if (element.name == 'user[first_name]' && element.value != ""){
        $('#first_name_error').addClass('valid');
      }else{
        $('#first_name_error').removeClass('valid');
      } 
      if (element.name == 'user[last_name]' && element.value != ""){
        $('#last_name_error').addClass('valid');
      }else{
        $('#last_name_error').removeClass('valid');
      }
    },
    rules : {
      "user[first_name]" : {
        required : true
      },
      "user[last_name]" : {
        required : true
      },
    },
    messages : {
      "user[first_name]" : {
        required : "Please enter your name."
      },
      "user[last_name]" : {
        required : "Please enter your name."
      }
    }
          });
        });
    </script>

<style>
.error{
    color: red;
  }

  p.valid {
    background: url('../assets/success.png') left -1px no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  }

  label.error {
    background: url('../assets/error.png') left -1px no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #792121;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  }

</style>
```

After submitting form it's not giving any alert and in console it is showing **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string** for alert and it is not showing any error message for first_name and last_name.

Comment: You are supposed to pass a proper object as parameter to `.validate`. Certainly not what you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use the builtin method like:

```
$('.user_form_validation').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       alert($('#user_first_name').val());
    }
});
```

The issue is you are placing an alert in the javascript object literal:

```
{
 alert($('#user_first_name').val());
}
```

As you have assigned the `.validate()` method to a jquery object and this method takes an object as an argument. Which should be an object with key and values.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.`validate()` function validates the form.To alert the field value.You can make use of jquery events.As below.Click the submit button..e

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <%= form_for(user, :html=>{:class=>'user_form_validation'}) do |f| %>
       <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :first_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :first_name%>
       </div>

       <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :last_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :last_name%>
       </div>
       <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Create",:id => "submit_button" %>
       </div>
    <% end%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#submit_button').click(function(){
            alert($('#user_first_name').val());
          });
        });
    </script>
```

If you want to validate your form try like this..Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xs5vrrso/
AND

http://jsfiddle.net/xs5vrrso/4018/

Comment: By using $('.user_form_validation').click({
            alert($('#user_first_name').val());
          }); it is working but I want $('.user_form_validation').valiadte({
            alert($('#user_first_name').val());
          }); like that. For .validate it is not working

Comment: for validation you have to set fileds `rules and messages`.

Comment: Place your alert code inside `submitHandler: function(){alert($('#user_first_name'.val())};`.

Comment: If I place alert inside of submitHandler that time only alert is working but remaining functionality is not workiing

Comment: follow fiddle..not need extra parameters.